# Highcharts auto refresh in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am working on asp.net MVC 5. I have created 4 different types of charts in it which are viewing on same page. I am getting data from a meter at almost 15-20 seconds interval. All i want to do is to refresh my charts after each 15/20 seconds so for every new entry in DB i should not refresh my page manually. For this i have used `javascript setInterval` in my graph view like bellow

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MultiGraph',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#c1").html(result);
        }
    });        
    alert("hello");
}, 3000);
```

Bellow are my `divs` in which i have placed my charts

```
<div id="c1">
    <div id="container1" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>


    <div id="container2" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>


    <div id="container3" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>


    <div id="container4" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>
</div>
```

At `$(window).on('load', function () { }` i have placed my 4 charts initialization like bellow

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({//rendered to container1});
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({//rendered to container2});
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({//rendered to container3});
var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({//rendered to container4});
```

All the data in charts are coming in array format

So after running my page look like bellow image

[image]

After i press `Ok` i get bellow

[image]

I don't know why it's happening, i just want to refresh/reload the charts only but all i am getting the above results as it's refresh the whole page also on refresh i am unable to view my charts

Moreover my charts are placed in a view and this view is following the main `layout` i.e. else charts and search bar all my view is coming from layout

**UPDATE:**

Bellow is the image which is showing me the data in `result`

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: don't ajax the same page, ajax only the content of the charts man

Comment: What if i place my charts in a partial view and then reload this partial view ?

Comment: its a better situation than the current one

Comment: @madalinivascu tried but it's giving me the same result

Comment: then go with data only and reinitialize the chart each time

Comment: @madalinivascu can you please provide me any link for it ?

Comment: looks like you are rendering view again in your ajax call. what you can do is make your server side method returns `Json`

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `setInterval` it repeats everything inside on that clause, it keeps adding HighChart object in that object.

What you can do is add `beforeSend` in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/MultiGraph',
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (result) {
            $("#c1").empty(); //empty first the div
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#c1").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried it  but not of any use

Comment: So i don't have to use success function?

Comment: what is the output of your `result` in you ajax code? looks like you are rendering a view in your post